# Reading Data from Switch pins Tiva c Launcpad

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I am trying to write code when I press the switch (PF0) the led should be on but my code did not work. I am sure I do all configuration why program don't read data coming from switchs?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SYSCTL_RCGC2_R              (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400FE108))
#define SYSCTL_RCGC2_GPIOF          0x00000020 // Port F Clock Gating Control
#define GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400253FC))
#define GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025400))
#define GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025510))
#define GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4002551C))
#define GPIO_PORTF_LOCK_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025520))
#define GPIO_PORTF_CR_R         (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025524))
#define GPIO_PORTF_AMSEL_R      (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025528))
#define GPIO_PORTF_PCTL_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4002552C))

#define PF0 (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025004))     //0x04 
#define PF4 (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025040))           //0x40

void delay(int sec);
int cond;
int k = 2;

int main(void){
    
    SYSCTL_RCGC2_R = SYSCTL_RCGC2_GPIOF;
    GPIO_PORTF_LOCK_R = 0x4C4F434B; // unlock PF0
    GPIO_PORTF_CR_R = 0x1F;               // can be written 0001.1111
    GPIO_PORTF_AMSEL_R =0x00;       //disableanalog function
    GPIO_PORTF_PCTL_R = 0x00;               // Port control
    GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0x0E;        //0x00001110  leds output swtichs input
    GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R = 0x11;              // pull register active for PF0 and PF4 (switches) 0001.0001
    GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R = 0x0E;                //0x00001110  leds output swtichs input
    PF0 = GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R^0x01; //1  Negative logic will be positive
    PF4 = GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R^0x10; //1
    
    while(1){
        if(PF0 == 0x01){
            GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R = 0x02; // Red for i sec 0x04= blue  yellow = 0x0A
            delay(1+k);
            
        }       
    return 0;
}
}
void delay(int sec){
    int c = 1, d = 1;
    for( c = 1; c <= sec; c++)
        for( d = 1; d <= 4000000; d++){}
        }
```

I follow this steps;

1. Activate clock
2. Unlock GPIO PortF
3. CR configuration to allow changes PF4-0
4. Disable analog on PF
5. Configure Port Control Register
6. Setting Direction Register
7. Disable AF if enabled earlier
8. Enable Digital I/o DEN

Problem solved via putting following lines into the while loop.

- PF0 = GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R^0x01; //1  Negative logic will be positive
- PF4 = GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R^0x10; //1

Comment: change delay to this volatile int c = 1, d = 1;

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: So which part does not work?  The input or the blinking?  if you remove the switch/button code the blinker works fine yes?

Comment: yes, work fine and I guess program did not capture the switch input. Maybe because of clock speed.

Comment: The switch is being read only once at startup.  You probably want to read the switch repeatedly.  Move the `PF0 = ` line into the `while(1)` loop.

Comment: also turn off the led if the switch is not asserted.

Comment: @kkrambo That's is the true answer, I put that lines into the while loop than it works. Thank you.